# Is there a way to convert html to image using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to convert HTML to image,
I tried this via the [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot), but when the html is height than the display screen, the image is cropped

```
/// Convert Html to Image
Future<File> htmlToImage(
  String html, String targetPath, String fileName) async {
    Uint8List img = await screenshotController.captureFromWidget(MediaQuery(
        data: const MediaQueryData(),
        child: Html(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            data: html,
        ),
  ));

  File file = await File('$targetPath/$fileName.jpg').create();
  file.writeAsBytesSync(img);

  return file;
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this, or can this problem be solved

Comment: You need a headless browser so you can have a virtual size that may be greater than the current window. The package `flutter_inappwebview` has a `HeadlessInAppWebView`, I do not see a example in the documentation but probably you can google for a solution. To take a screenshot you need to get the a `InAppWebViewController` and call the `takeScreenshot` method.